# Most efficient way to load a 10MB+ bundle.js in html

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

In my project, web pack is generating minified bundle.js of 10 MB+ but when I load that whole bundle.js in an HTML page using HtmlPlugin and try to run the project then it takes a lot of time to land on the homepage. How can I make this faster?

Comment: By not using as much JS? I mean, 20MB minified is a huge amount of code to process. How did it get that big?

Comment: it's around 8 MB @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: mining bitcoin?

Comment: Something's gone wrong then. You should be aiming for a few hundred kB, even with a relatively big app. Research various ways to reduce bundle size, or things you might be doing wrong. There's a whole bunch of articles and posts and such about reducing bundle size

Comment: do you have large size assets in your app ?

Comment: I have integrated two standalone react app in a single react app (Dashboard) and bundling the whole in one @SakhiMansoor

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this ? Is there one Main Layout from where you can navigate to the apps ? Are they going to be hosted under the same domain ?

Comment: Yeah you are correct @SakhiMansoor

Comment: added an explanation below.

Answer (score 0):

There are workarounds which you can use to load or improve performance of your app.

1. Separate app code(components etc...) and api code (react etc...)

You need to bundle them separately as bundle.js and vendor.js. Now use browser caching which will make sure loading of vendor.js only once. I believe you most of the code will be api code only. This will increase app load performance as only app code will be loaded.

2. Making use of async loading of modules.

You can make use of async loading of modules which will create chunks out of your bundle.js. Chunk which is piece of js code will be loaded when required by route or module.

Comment: I have created 2 MB of 10 chunks of my bundled, how can I add those into HTML page dynamically ?

Comment: web pack will help you automatically achieve this. check this https://medium.com/@cominsoon_io/optimize-performance-by-10x-for-a-react-single-page-application-1a9c602cdae8

Comment: Thanks @Anil Kumar

Answer (score 0):

@Akash If you have two standalone apps under same domain. You need to enable [Webpack Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) in your project. So it will load bundles dynamically. In each case, only required app bundles will be downloaded whenever you navigate to one of these apps.

> For your concern regarding how to add chunks in `index.html`?

**Webpack** is responsible for this, it uses `runTimeChunk` in optimization which dynamically loads relevant bundles.

---

Further improvements will include:

- You must enable [Webpack Caching](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) -This will let your browser download packages when the bundle hash number changes otherwise it will load bundle in miliseconds from cache.

I hope this would give you insights how you can intelligently optimize you app.
Let me know if you have any queries further.